# how to keep the system date & time unchanged in VMWare snapshot?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I created MacOS Virtual Machine snapshot in VMware Fusion. I want the system date and time to be unchanged in the snapshot. I've unchecked "Synchronize Time" in Virtual Machine Settings. But everywhere I launched the snapshot the system date will be updated to the current system time. Any ideas how to fix this issue? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you also disabled the Network Adapter so that NTP can't sync?